# Using "that do" instead of "to do"

Tags: relative-clauses, causatives

Can I write this sentence

> In this paper, we present an approach and a system, called ABDES, for constructing web wrappers **to extract** data records from a web page.

as

> In this paper, we present an approach and a system, called ABDES, for constructing web wrappers **that extract** data records from a web page.

Which is better? Or maybe it is better to say

> In this paper, we present an approach and a system, called ABDES, to construct web wrappers **for extracting** data records from a web page.

Comment: I don't think there's a nickel's worth of difference between them.

Comment: @StoneyB thanks, what about the third one I just added.

Comment: Now I think maybe **constructing web wrappers** is redundant

Comment: I prefer the ones with *for*. The new one is just a tiny bit ambiguous: it might be understood that constructing wrappers is the purpose of your presentation, not the purpose of your approach and system.

Comment: I can't speak to that redundancy without knowing vastly more about your system!

Comment: @StoneyB I don't know how inviting to chat works, can we chat a bit?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27553/discussion-between-ahmad-and-stoneyb).

Comment: What is with this insane number of random close votes?!

Comment: @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M I already noticed many recent questions got down vote and close vote, suspiciously by a certain member

Answer (score 1):

The difference is very slight.

> ...wrappers **to extract**...

tells us that the "system ABDES"'s most important purpose is to construct "web wrappers", and the whole shebang has *one goal* -- to extract data.

> ...wrappers **that extract**...

tells us that the wrappers are the ones that do the extracting.  (This is a bit weird, by the way).  The system is described, and its purpose is somewhat convoluted and murky, but a specialist will probably find it useful.

> ...wrappers **for extracting**...

tells us about the system and that its primary goal is *to construct web wrappers*.  If you need extracting data, you probably know the importance of those wrappers, which the "system ABDES" will happily create.  The wrappers are used in the process of extracting data.  Somehow.